# Want to Split string in mysql using SUBSTRING_INDEX

Tags: php, mysql, string, split

I need to assign **AAA-BBB-CCC** in 3 different MySQL variables.

Here's the unsuccessful code:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `testdepot`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test_dlr`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test_dlr`(IN id VARCHAR(250),OUT temp1 VARCHAR(50)
,OUT temp2 VARCHAR(50),OUT temp3 VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE t1 VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE t2 VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE t3 VARCHAR(255);
SET @t1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '-', 1);
SET @t2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '-', -1);
SET @t3 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '-', -1);
SELECT @t1 INTO temp1;
SELECT @t2 INTO temp2;
SELECT @t3 INTO temp3;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

How can I separate above **AAA-BBB-CCC** string?

Comment: Please confirm that `@t1` and `@t2` are affected as expected, but the proble is only with `@t3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET @t3 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '-', -2), '-', 1);
```

There are other ways to do it, but I find this one quite amusing :)

Comment: you are missing one comma in the last part of your statement ``SET @t3 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '-', -2), '-', 1);``