# Insert n number of rows into table when input string contains n number of fields in mysql

Tags: mysql

I do have a requirement like when two inputs are passed as input to stored proc, inserting into another table need to happen and the number of rows will depend on number of fields passed in input.

I have tried to create a stored proc but its only inserting taking field length as 1

```
BEGIN

Declare valu varchar(200);
Declare valu2 varchar(200);
Declare fwo varchar(200);
Declare fwo2 varchar(200);
declare len int;
Declare sl int;
Declare valu3 varchar(255);
Declare jval varchar(255);

set @fwo = (select replace(pinput1,',', ''));
set @fwo2 = (select replace(pinput2,',', ''));
-- select @fwo;
set @len = (select length(@fwo));
-- select @fwo,@len;
set @sl = 1;
if @len >0 then 
increment: repeat
set @valu = SUBSTRING(@fwo, @sl , 1);
set @valu2 = SUBSTRING(@fwo2, @sl , 1);

set @jval = JSON_OBJECT('id',@valu2,'policy',@valu);

INSERT INTO `Example`(`Column1`,`Column2`) values(@valu2,@jval);

set @sl = @sl+1;

UNTIL @sl > @len END repeat increment ;

END if ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When the input are 1,2,3 and a,b,c the insertion is happening correctly, but when we pass 11,12,13 and ab,cd,ef the insertion is happening likethe above condition inputs.The same repetes when the lenght increases more than 1.

Can someone suggestion me to solve this issue

Comment: First you remove every comma (`,`) in your input, which, as far as I understand your input, will mean you loose any information about the fields (and especially the number of fields). Then you take every single character of that modified input (`substring(...,1)`) and add a row for each. You should probably have a look at e.g. [Want to Split string in mysql using SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111493/want-to-split-string-in-mysql-using-substring-index)

Comment: I have tried with SUBSTRING_INDEX, but it's not working for me

Comment: Well, you tried without `substring_index`, and it isn't working for you either. `Substring_index` would work, just use the example in the link EXACTLY as it it used there (using `substring_index` two times to get one value). "not working" is a very broad description of what is wrong, so try it, and if it doesn't work, add it to your question with a description of what doesn't work so we can fix it.